# C# error with converting string to int in unity3d

Tags: c#, arrays, string, list, unity-game-engine

I'm having a problem in Unity with C#, I'm trying to create a List or Array that has all the information I need.

> 0000, 0001,0002, etc.

I want to put this into an List/Array and use this information to instantiate a model on a character selection screen. However, this is the part of code where everything starts to get messed up.

I'm just trying to read out the numbers and add them into the list.

```
    void Start () {
    gestureListener = this.GetComponent<GestureListener>();
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfModels; i++) {
        string b = i.ToString("0000");
        List<string> mylist = new List<string>(new string[b]);
        Debug.Log (mylist);
        break;
    }
}
```

I get this error:

```
error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type `string' to `int'
```

The error happens on **line 5**, but to me this seems an to be an irreplaceable line...

The variable B is a `string` so I wouldn't know why the lists sees it as an `int`.

Please let me know if you can help, much appreciated!

Comment: The problem is with this part: `new string[b]`

Comment: @Dmitry `b` is a string, that also won't work. Did you mean `i`?

Comment: because if i replace new string[b] with just b it gives me this error:
error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for `System.Collections.Generic.List<string>.List(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>)' has some invalid arguments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If  you are trying to instantiate a list to then add elements to this list then you got it wrong. You are currently instantiating a new list with just one element every time you iterate. In other words, you are not putting the list to use, you are just creating a new one every time you loop.

Create your List of Strings outside the loop then add to it from inside the loop.

You should have something like this to populate the list.

```
void Start() 
{
    List<string> mylist = new List<string>();
    gestureListener = this.GetComponent<GestureListener>();
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfModels; i++) {
        string b = i.ToString("0000");
        myList.Add(b);
        Debug.Log (mylist);
        break;
    }
}
```

With that said, at the end of your `for-loop` your `myList` will have a collection of `models` per say. You can then iterate that collection to see all the elements you have pushed.

```
foreach(var item in mylist)
{
   //Do whatever with each Item.
}
```

If you need more examples, take a look at [DotNetPerls List Examples](http://www.dotnetperls.com/list)
and this [video example](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/intermediate/scripting/lists-and-dictionaries) with Unity in mind.

Comment: i'm working with kinect and i'm trying to achieve a character selection that reacts on a swipe movement, it has to instantiate the next number every time i run the forloop

Comment: My code is the same as Ron Beyer, what made you accept that answer if it doesn't help you? Your collection of numbers will be instantiated before entering the loop, inside the loop you simply add a number to the collection then break out of the loop, That Logic makes no sense. What exactly is it that you are trying to do here, try to break it down better and maybe we can help you out better.

Comment: i'm almost done with it, but in short;i used your answer because after i drew out how i want the code to loop i came to the conclusion yours is the best answer, therefore i'm accepting yours for this case.
i made my code so that this forloop picks up all the numbers of models that are in my hierarchy and puts them in a list.
then i used a second variable to count swipes, and used this number to pick out the number from the forloop which enables me to get the right model every time, with an automatic piece in it that checks for new models just so i dont have to add everything manually everytime

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, this helped me very much!

Comment: @niels Glad you got it working, and happy to help. Take care.

Answer (score 2):

```
void Start () {
    gestureListener = this.GetComponent<GestureListener>();
    List<string> myList = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfModels; i++) {
        string b = i.ToString("0000");
        myList.Add(b);
        Debug.Log (mylist);
        break;
    }
    //myList is populated with all the numberOfModels here.
}
```

Don't create a new list inside the loop. The way you are doing it now, you are trying to create a new list (which you throw away anyway), that has progressively larger empty string arrays. For example with a `numberOfModels` of 100, you would have 100! empty string elements in the list (if you saved it).

Just create a list outside of the for loop, and add the string `b` to the list inside the loop.

Comment: thankyou for your answer, as it made me see what i really needed.